# SQL - LEFT JOIN takes an extremely long time to execute

Tags: sql, performance, left-join

I'm trying to see if there are any rows in table A which I've missed in table B.

For this, I'm using the following query:

```
SELECT t1.cusa
FROM patch t1
LEFT JOIN trophy t2
ON t2.titleid = t1.titleid
WHERE t2.titleid IS NULL
```

And the query worked before, but now that the `trophy` table has nearly 200.000 rows, it's extremely slow. I've waited 5 minutes for it to execute but it was still loading and timed out eventually.

Is there any way to speed this query up?

Comment: Performance tuning in SQL Server isn't always black and white. In general, indexing the identifiers which are used in the `JOIN` will help, but it also depends on how heavily the server is loaded, the memory available, disk IO, table size, etc. 200k records is pretty small though. Try checking server load and look at the query plan to see which operations are most expensive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this and it might perform a bit better!

```
SELECT t1.cusa
FROM patch t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
    FROM trophy t2
    WHERE t2.titleid = t1.titleid );
```

Comment: That indeed really does speed up this query!

Comment: @AppelFlap Glad it helped!

Answer (score 1):

Adding Indexes to titleId on both tables (but especially t2) is the quickest way to get better performance.  200K records is nothing for SQL Server.